# Set Request Header jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck in a very strange problem, I want to send an extra param **Authorization** in my ajax request to a service, just like this

```
Request headers
Authorization: bearer t-3e57cc74-3e7a-4fc7-9bbb-f6c83252db01
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=908D73C50F09E75C9A0D674C4CB33D2F; ROUTEID=.1; __unam=3c3246b-13bc693352d-aa1535c-1
```

But Using this code

```
headerParams = {'Authorization':'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e'};
    obj = {
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.sandbox.slcedu.org/api/rest/v1/students/test1',
        headers: headerParams,
    data: [],
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
    }
};

  jQuery.ajax(obj);
```

It send like this which is not passing the value, also its request type become OPTION instead of GET, here is console log

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers  authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    api.sandbox.slcedu.org
Origin  http://localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
```

Can anyone tell me how can I pass it like this
Authorization: bearer t-3e57cc74-3e7a-4fc7-9bbb-f6c83252db01

Thanks

Comment: I checked it, its because of Cross Domain Call, How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Have you considered using jsnop in the ajax request?

Answer (score 78):

Using the beforeSend pre-request callback we can achieve this.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.sandbox.slcedu.org/api/rest/v1/students/test1',
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e');
},
data: {},
success: function () { },
error: function () { },
});
```

Comment: it works, but it should be "Bearer" instead of "bearer"

Answer (score 28):

And you can set it for all requests with ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '...');
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case I needed to set this for an X-CSRF-Token header and this solved my issue.

Comment: Please note that on their [docs page](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) they strongly recommend against this. "This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings."

Answer (score 23):

Another option, specify with "headers" key.

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.example.com/action",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJraWQiOiJBbWZJSXU3UFhhdXlUbHM3UmNyZmNIQUd1MUdCWkRab2I0U05GaVJuWUFJPSIsImFsZyI6IlYYYjU2In0.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.fV4bgaKwXx-HjrBmGtBnSzaDHdP0JEeJ0sbE6MzuOJYWafT5gWfh9pLtkpUv-mgsnX3cVIWDVKC0H8_XM4ziUhsulZIRBwTiSca0CfABvanuMdbdjk1iK70aUxsrjHX0gK4SDUi4Zl6JNGws_SRbVi9Yq_ntx7ttXfUpZHjimfZ2mLidOLUruYctG1V_gU-dLD6CARCUbGh5aRk5nwX_5-HBUTbBVPYK3sXcVg2YRk63d-p3TITA5hoOEj9lxtHs3ZM7ZqNPl0XPUGghxdbvWnpSIUKrFLugRHqCiWxC38ZYiBhP0NDYoEMaOI-UrnEH1W6j-kr3fnH2LD5wOMJ_8Q"
    },
    "data": {
        "someData": someData
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
})
```