# POST request using ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I met some problems when I try to send the POST request using ajax in Django. I already research some topics here, but still can't find the way to solved them.

Here is my javascript code that follow [this solution](http://blog.merren.net/2013/02/django-ajax-post-and-csrf.html):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{% url home %}',
    data: {selected_folders: formData,
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
});
```

I also try the [solution from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url home %}',
        data: {selected_folders: formData,
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
    });
});
```

Here is my `view.py`

```
def home(request):        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Call_Other_Class()
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

My goal is to send the POST request from `home.html` to itself, and when `home.html` get the POST request, it will call other classes to do something else. I am not sure where to put the CSRF token in the template and if my code in `view.py` is correct or not.

Thanks for your reading and solve my problems.

**Edit:**

I edited my javascript code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url home %}',
        data: {selected_folders: formData},
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li id='key1'></li>
    <li id='key2'></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: csrf_token should be a header, not part of POST data. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19766468/3945375)

Comment: whats your form HTML ?

Comment: What does your POST get? BTW, I have no idea what your HTML does.

Answer (score 2):

For Js:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: '{% url home %}',
       data: {selected_folders: formData,
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]"),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
    });
});
```

For **view.py**:

```
def home(request):        
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    Call_Other_Class()
return render_to_response('home.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is using the online documentation.
From what I recall:

- first call a GET in Ajax and in the answer, force [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator
- then keep the CSRF cookie, you have all the detail explanation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#s-ajax).