# Why is this jQuery Ajax request not sending the authorization request header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, authentication

I am calling a web service with a jQuery Ajax request and I need to pass an authorization header. So I have something like the below...

```
  $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://emmawatson.com/askForaDate",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YXBpdHVybnRvQGFwaS5jb206QXBpMzIxJDEyMw');
            },
            success: handleData
        });
```

When I look at the request headers in the outgoing request, I only see this..

```
 Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
 Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
```

I was expecting to see something like this..

```
 authorization:Basic YXBpdHVybnRvQGFwaS5jb206QXBpMzIxJDEyMw
```

So it looks like the authorization request header is not being sent.

I also tried the other approaches suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010851/set-request-header-jquery-ajax) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax).

Could anyone tell me what I am missing? How do I get the actual header value to show up in the request headers?

Comment: From which url are you make the call? Do you have any error in console? If so could you paste here please?

Comment: the outgoing request with those `Access-Control-Request` headers will be `OPTIONS` (CORS preflight) - the Authorization header will only be sent once the preflight **succeeds** - which I'm guessing is not the case - in the GET request that follows a successful preflight check. This is standard CORS behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I believe that jQuery will only supply the credentials if a challenge is received, like what Jaromanda said in their comment above.