# jQuery include Bearer token in all requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jwt

I am creating a simple jQuery powered application, which uses `JWT` via `Flask` on the back-end. I do not want to use a more feature rich client-side framework.

I can interface with the API using the token via `$.ajax` such as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXX")
    }
});
```

However, I cannot interface with the 'simple' HTML pages as the `GET` request does not include the `Bearer` token.

If I attempt to use the same method as above, but using a `GET` type, the `ajax` can load the page, however the new content is not displayed in the browser (`XMLHttpRequest`).

Is there a way I can access and display `GET` data in the users browser using jQuery?

Comment: Should work with GET. Possible something wrong with server-side code? Check answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766468/1397220) to see if you did something wrong. (seems okay for me)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have a similar snippet above. the GET request itself works fine (I can see in the network tab), but the browser page itself does not refresh/reload the content which is requested over ajax

Comment: I thought question was about `However, I cannot interface with the 'simple' HTML pages as the GET request does not include the Bearer token.`

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I can make GET/POST requests to the API. This works fine. But any direct browser requests do not work. As the bearer token is not included. For example, if you visit a link /users, the token will not be inlcuded in the request.

Comment: Then you'll have to alter the server-side script so that if the request is a simple page request, he responses with html and only for ajax calls it should check for the token.

Comment: Add done callback `$.ajax(...).done(function(data) {console.log(data);});`

Comment: If you have a tokken : `$.ajax({...,headers: {'X-Auth-Token' : token}});`