# how to get oauth token in jQuery

Tags: jquery, oauth, postman, token

I have the below set up that I use to fetch oauth token in postman. How do I write this as an ajax call in jQuery

Postman Details :

```
tokenUrl => someUrl
grant_type => client_credentials
client_id => xxxxx
client_secret => yyyyy
client authentication => **Send as Basic Auth Header**
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is this link useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010851/set-request-header-jquery-ajax

Comment: I tried the examples mentioned. It is a cross domain request. The error I receive is Access to XMLHttpRequest at '..../oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:8000', but only one is allowed.  The response headers has 2 values for Access-Control-Allow-Origin = . * and localhost. httpd.conf has only one entry for Access-Control-Allow-Origin so not sure from where the second one is being added