# Connecting an API with a Token

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, token, sanctum

I need some help with the laravel application.
I am using Token Sanctum and securing certain routes.
What happens is that I don't know how to do it and I wonder if someone could give me an idea.

When I log in and generate a new token that is stored in a session on the frontend (react).
But when my front tries to connect with the back, it can't because the route is protected.

I do not know how I could do to request the route, the front inform the token saved in the session and thus be able to access the route.

Could someone give me an idea?

Thanks in advance...

I don't have the code for now, as I honestly have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You mean access the api? Did you try ajax, axios, or fetch?

Comment: If you already have the user token generated and stored in your frontend session, you can use that to access api endpoints using ajax, axios or fetch. Search for using bearer tokens in ajax

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766468

Comment: in the setRequestHeader param, the right side's value should be `Bearer` + [space] + token

Comment: "it can't because the route is protected" ... What error exactly you'are getting